# Appending certain amount of characters from one list to another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got to create a program where a user enters their first name, last name and student ID and creates a password using the first 3 letters/numbers from each.

I've got the first name in one list, last name in another and student ID in another and was then going to append 3 characters from each to a new list called "login".

How do I do this, or how do I append just 3 characters from my original raw_input into one list?

Comment: post your program here

Comment: When you say list do you mean string? You keep using the word list for things that really shouldn't be a in a list. I find it hard to believe you have a list for username, a different list for password, and another one for studentID, I think you mean strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you really want and you keep using the word list for things that probably are not lists. You say you have a list for firstname, lastname, studentID, I think you mean you have a list containing firstname, lastname, studentID. It's possible you have a string for each of these, but I'm going to guess you actually have a list considering how much you used the word list

#### If you actually have a list (like you said)

```
someList = ["dog says hi", "cat says hi", "moo goes cow"]
print("".join([x[:3] for x in someList]))
#dogcatmoo
```

#### If you actually have three strings

```
firstname = "joe"
lastname = "smith"
studentID = "12434234"

wordsList = [firstname, lastname, studentID]
print("".join([x[:3] for x in wordsList]))
#joesmi124
```

#### If you actually have a different list for username, password, and id

You should use strings instead...

Comment: Changed from lists to strings and used your second code posted above, thanks!